# Put joined rows into a merged list

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the LINQ to SQL query below which works fine, except that I would like to get the "items" selected from "table3" to be put into a single entity object, instead what I'm getting is a new entity with the same Id but different item for each row.

What do I need to do to achieve this?

Thanks!

```
var result =
        from table1 in db.Table1
        join table2 in db.Table2 on table1.fkId equals table2.fkId
        join table3 in db.Table3 on table2.fkAid equals table3.Id into items
        select new Entity
        {
            Id = table1.Id,
            Name = table1.Name,
            Items = items.Select(x => new AEntity { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).ToList()
        };

return result.ToList();
```

Edit to elaborate:

From the code above I could get, for example, the following result (pseudocode):

```
{
    Entity
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "1",
        Items
        {
            AEntity
            {
                Name = "33"
                Id = 33
            }
        }
    },
    Entity
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "1",
        Items
        {
            AEntity
            {
                Id = 44,
                Name = "44"
            }
        }
    },
    Entity
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "2",
        Items
        {
            AEntity
            {                    
                Id = 55,
                Name = "55"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I want this:

```
{
    Entity
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "1",
        Items
        {
            AEntity
            {
                Id = 33,
                Name = "33"
            },
            AEntity
            {
                Id = 44,
                Name = "44"
            }
        }
    },
    Entity
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "2",
        Items
        {
            AEntity
            {                    
                Id = 55,
                Name = "55"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I added some pseudo-code of the data to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again another person falls victim to "trying to do SQL in Linq". The correct way to do this (in Linq) is...*

```
var items = context.Entities.Include(x => x.AEntities).ToList();
```

However if you ARE trying to learn to use an ORM, FOR THE LOVE OF ALL THAT IS HOLY DO NOT USE LINQ2SQL. Its broken, unsupported and out of date.

PLEASE USE Entity Framework.

Now you should google Entity Framework Many to Many or One to Many Associations.

Failing that...

```
var items = from item1 in db.Table1
            select new 
            {
                Id = table1.Id,
                Name = table1.Name,
                Items = db.Table3
                          .Where(x => db.Table2
                                .Where(t2 => t2.fkId == item1.fkId)
                                .Select(t2 => t2.fkAid)
                          .Contains(x.Id)).ToList()
            };
```

But that just looks ugly.

*[Table 2 looks like the age old pattern of, "Databases can't do Many to Many, so we are going to put in an intermediate table that has no data what-so-ever".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092322/linq-to-sql-many-to-many-relationship-without-a-third-class)

Comment: Yeah I normally use Entity Framework but I can't control it in this case...with that said your linq2sql does look a bit neater than the other solution, however I'm getting a "Delegate 'System.Func<...> does not take 1 arguments" from the Table3 Where clause.

Comment: ...and yeah I agree about Table 2.

Comment: Nevermind, was the variable that had the incorrect type. Now it's working, thanks a lot! And sorry for the linq2sql ;)

Comment: I was wondering about one more thing, if I use the following technique on another field below items, it will only do a left outer join on one of them...the other field will be queried separately. Why is that and how can it be solved?

Comment: Not sure I understand your meaning. Neither the less trying to fix Linq2SQL is a lost cause. For one thing, I have never taken a look at the source code to Linq2SQL.

Comment: If I do "...Items = db.Table3.Where(..." on another field in the select new, for example "...Items2 = db.Table4.Where(..." then only Table3 is left outer joined. Yeah, I guess what I should do is just ask the project owner to go with entity framework :/